# Setting a domain on the default connect.sid browser cookie in an express app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session-cookies

OK so I have an express/mongo app that operates based on subdomains. I have read that it's possible to have a session ID cookie be available to subdomains by setting the domain of the cookie to .mydomain.com

That should work, but I can't figure out how to get that property into the default browser cookie (connect.sid).

I'm using express-session for sessions, connect-mongo for persisting the sessions, and of course cookie-parser to make that all work.

There seems to be a few different places where I might be able to set this property, but none of them seem to have any effect on the actual cookie I see in Chrome's dev tools. :(

Here's the app config block:

```
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser('judy_has_cooties', { domain: '.' + app.settings.domainToUse })); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});   
app.use(session({
    secret: app.config.secret,
    cookie: { 
        domain: '.' + app.settings.domainToUse, 
        path: '/', 
        httpOnly: true, 
        secure: false, 
        maxAge: null 
    },
    store: new MongoStore({url: app.config.db }, function(err){
        console.log('session store is up.');
    })
}));
app.use(subdomain({ 
    base : app.settings.domainToUse + '', 
    removeWWW : true 
}));
//app.use(morgan());
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.server = require('http').createServer(app);

mongoose.connect(app.config.db);

require('./config/configure-routes')();

// Start server
app.server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log(">>>>> Node server is listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

I don't get the connect.sid cookie in the browser until after I login, so I assume it's being done when I call sessionStore.set(). What I'm not clear on is what is setting the actual browser cookie. When I log out the req.session object from some route auth middleware I see all the correct settings, but the actual browser cookie doesn't reflect these settings.

Am I right in thinking that the session cookie is actually just in the session store on the server and not in the browser? And the connect.sid is just a handle to look up those cookies?

If so how can I add more data to the browser cookie to get it to persist between subdomains?

Thanks and sorry for possibly not understanding how sessions and cookie work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! Ok I really hope this helps someone because I was banging my head agains the wall for 2 days.

So, apparently this was not an issue related to node, or my server config at all. It's purely a cookie problem.

Cookies it seems are super whiney about the patterns they receive in the domain= field. If something is not 1000% correct it will barf and just not set the cookie at all.

A domain with a port number like :3000 will not work and localhost will not work with the .localhost formatting for enabling subdomains. It requires a . some place in the domain name in order to be valid.

To do this locally I had to get into my local DNS settings and setup a .dev url to be redirected to localhost. Pain the ass! Here's a great link for that though if you're on OSX.

http://clintberry.com/2011/wildcard-sub-domains-on-osx-web-development-on-localhost/

Once that was setup then it worked like gangbusters!

Good luck padewan.